# Installing a SIM Toolkit applet on a Java Card fails with SW 6A88

Tags: javacard, sim-card, globalplatform, sim-toolkit

I have been trying to install a very small sample applet using SIM toolkit features, such as `uicc.toolkit.ProactiveHandler`. After writing the applet and generating a file, `sampleapp.cap`, using the `converter` tool from the Java Card SDK I was unable to install `sampleapp.cap` file on the Java Card I was using for development. I am using global platform pro, and am getting a `6a88` SW in response when trying to load the applet.

To build:

`converter -classdir build -applet $APP_AID sampleapp.SampleToolkitApp sampleapp $PKG_AID 1.0` (generates `build/sampleapp/javacard/sampleapp.cap`)

To install (with java card reader insterted):

`gp -d -v --install build/sampleapp/javacard/sampleapp.cap`

output:

```
A>> T=1 (4+0000) 00A40400 00 
A<< (0018+2) (45ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD AID: A000000003000000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected block size: 255
A>> T=1 (4+0008) 80500000 08 6CB661C0B31315CB 00
A<< (0028+2) (117ms)     00003126960097F931740102007110F669CA335E5BAF5F8BF724DC1E 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Host challenge: 6CB661C0B31315CB
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card challenge: 007110F669CA335E
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Card reports SCP02 with version 1 keys
[DEBUG] PlaintextKeys - session keys: 
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:5246B7B44BB830257A6546CF9FF70413 KCV: 9E246B
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:250DC88427E2C97165280D315EB39640 KCV: 8FE051
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:AD1197EAA5AAB912CB91F82C7B7DC125 KCV: 55D1A7
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Verified card cryptogram: 5BAF5F8BF724DC1E
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Calculated host cryptogram: 608223EB1CE199AA
A>> T=1 (4+0016) 84820100 10 608223EB1CE199AA6AA94AAC2B12D3C2
A<< (0000+2) (42ms) 9000
CAP file (v2.1) generated on Wed Jun 29 14:12:28 EDT 2016
By Sun Microsystems Inc. converter 1.3 with JDK 1.7.0_80 (Oracle Corporation)
Package: sampleapp v1.0 with AID B115737612
Applet: SampleToolkitApp with AID B1157376121E
Import: A0000000620101 v1.2
Import: A0000000090003FFFFFFFF8910710002 v2.6
Total code size: 445 bytes (672 with debug)
SHA256 (code):     E4E65C31237BDA2CF893A4145309C1DA541290028EF7E8B3AEEC1279C58DF805
SHA1   (code): 97C8E9C2E364E4185D501552430FCF65A80A9CCF
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28002 0A 4F00D59C73CC637DAD77 00
A<< (0000+2) (46ms) 6A86
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F28000 0A 4F0072678A1AE9D9D06E 00
A<< (0011+2) (50ms) 08A000000003000000079E 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F24000 0A 4F0006A4F0528D4EFB48 00
A<< (0009+2) (54ms) 064DF87F7FB8BE0700 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F22000 0A 4F0092C86D9389102AD4 00
A<< (0051+2) (68ms) 07A0000000035344010007A0000000035350010009534B544558544C4942010008A0000002270110000100054DF87F7FB80100 9000
A>> T=1 (4+0010) 84F21000 0A 4F001D7AC0FD69CBCB37 00
A<< (0000+2) (46ms) 6A81
[WARN] GlobalPlatform - GET STATUS failed for 80F21000024F0000 with 6a81
A>> T=1 (4+0026) 84E60200 1A 05B11573761208A0000000030000000000009BDAA789A47D5BB5
A<< (0001+2) (138ms) 00 9000
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
A<< (0000+2) (1s213ms) 6A88
pro.javacard.gp.GPException: LOAD failed SW: 6A88
    at pro.javacard.gp.GPException.check(GPException.java:66)
    at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:667)
    at pro.javacard.gp.GlobalPlatform.loadCapFile(GlobalPlatform.java:625)
    at pro.javacard.gp.GPTool.main(GPTool.java:518)
LOAD failed SW: 6A88
```

Using the SmartCafe Expert 3.2 72k, which I purchased as a Java Card. Also using JavaCard SDK 2.2.1, which is the supported version for that card, and have used both 3GPP TS 43.019 v6.0.0 STK API technical specification and ETSI TS 102 241 13.0.0 UICC API for Java Card.

The 6A88 SW indicates "referenced data not found". Is this something specific to my card, in that it hasn't implemented the STK stack?

Comment: As a follow up: Abraham's answer is correct. After further emails, it seems SIM cards for development in small quantities (i.e. 1 or 3) are not available to people who aren't big telcos. However, there might be some for sale on alibaba, ebay, or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SmartCafe Expert 3.2 72k](http://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/id~521/smartcafe-expert-3-2-72k/p/index.shtml) is a simple regular Java Card and does not contain SIM Toolkit APIs inside. So it can't install those applets that used SIM Toolkit APIs.

In the loading process, the  OPEN on the card is trying to make a link between your applet and the used libraries. As it can't find SIM Toolkit library there, it returns this error.

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion as much. Time to go shopping again, but I appreciate the answer.

Do you have any words of wisdom on knowing which Java Cards will support STK APIs? e.g. [if it says "Java card" and "SIM" in the description](http://www.smartcardfocus.com/shop/ilp/id~776/smartcafe-expert-6-0-80k-sim/p/index.shtml), is there a good chance it will support Java Card applets and STK APIs?

Comment: No. It is just a SIM sized regular card. You need to get a SIM with JavaCard capabilities. Ask your operator maybe.